# Change color of text inputs in Gmail Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am using Google Apps Script for Gmail Add-on.

Changing `secondaryColor` in the manifest file for a Gmail add-on does not change the color of form inputs (`TextInput`). It is written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests) that it will change the color of both buttons and form elements but it does not seem to be working for form elements.

Here is the code of my manifest file.

```
   {
  "gmail": {
    "name": "ColorTesting",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png",
    "primaryColor": "#428500",
    "secondaryColor": "#18A390",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {},
      "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
    }],
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}
```

This changes the color of buttons (`TextButton`) but does not change the color of input elements (`TextInput`)!

Am I doing anything wrong or is there any other way in which I can change the color of input elements?

Comment: @BirenPrajapti  Did you find a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue where the Radio buttons are colored green in spite of having a different secondaryColor in app manifest.

Comment: @JigarJain No solutions yet! I've reported this issue on [issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72353684)

Comment: Note that [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#LayoutProperties.FIELDS.secondaryColor) now only mentions button colors (although the issue is still not declined/closed).

Comment: @OlegValter seems like they've updated the documentation!

Comment: @BirenPrajapati - they did an extensive rework after releasing Workspace Add-ons, just noting for others that they will not find the reference you mentioned (too bad the original page wasn't indexed by the Wayback Machine). Very strange that we cannot properly colorize form controls with `CardService` after all these years.